# How to compare address of two void *

Tags: c, pointers

I have two `void *`, namely `void *a` and `void *b`. Lets say `a` is at `0x804ae0` and `b` is at `0x804aec`. How do I compare the two? I want to check if address of `a` is lower than address of `b`.

Comment: Have you *tried* to just compare them?

Comment: "I want to check if address of a is lower than address of b" - careful in your wording. There is a *world* of difference between the address *of* a pointer and the address a pointer *holds*.

Comment: "*I want to check if address of a is lower than address of b*": Are you sure you mean this? `a` is itself a pointer and so is `b`. If you just want to compare the pointers, you should be saying "I want to check if `a` is lower than `b`".

Comment: My bad on that. But the compiler raised issues and said comparision by invalid cast.

Comment: @graphics_master Please provide a MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the returned error then it can get fixed.

Answer (score 12):

The standard operators work on `void *` too:

```
if (a < b) ...
```

Comment: Is it defined how these pointers are compared in this case? As signed or unsigned values?

Comment: @dlask Signed/unsigned doesn't make sense for pointer addresses, so no. On the machine code level, the addresses are simply compared, and there is no such thing as "signed" existing there.

Comment: @dlask pointers don't have a sign. They are addresses. According to the standard, they don't even have to be numbers (although in all hardware that I know of, they are).

Comment: OK, but only numbers can be compared, and since it's allowed to compare pointers there must be a way to map pointers to numbers. CPUs usually support signed and unsigned operations so the compiler designer has to decide which kind of arithmetic operation to use in this case. No offence, I am just curious.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702161/pointer-comparisons-in-c-are-they-signed-or-unsigned

Comment: @dlask As far as C is concerned, 6.5.8: `"When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the
address space of the objects pointed to."` and so on. As far as the machine code is concerned, there exists no such thing as pointers, just addresses and possibly index registers meant to be used to hold addresses. There exists no CPU with negative addresses, so why would anyone would use signed comparison for addresses?

Comment: Comparison is valid iif the two pointers point to the same object (struct or array) or the logical location immediately after it. In either case `a<b` is true iff when casting the object they are part of to (char*) then `a` points to an element with a lower index than the one pointed to by `b`. That said few platforms will fail to perform a comparison (but will give an arbitrary and semantically meaningless result). If you're building some kind of cache that needs to apply an arbitrary order do cast to `uintptr_t` otherwise your code is (technically) non-compliant.

Comment: By 6.5.8/5, for data pointers this is viable so long as `a` and `b` fulfill the requirement that they address the same object, objects in an array, or hold the one-past address. If those conditions aren't met, this will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanAllen The specification is fully clear about typed pointers. The only problem here is with untyped pointers `void*`.

Comment: @dlask A reasonable point. Maybe this needs tagging 'language lawyer'. The specification isn't crystal clear about `void*` (C99 - 6.5.8) and given how opaque it is that they can't be subtracted (6.5.6) it's fair to ask whether they can be (relationally) compared. I think the practical answer is (to the limit of my knowledge) implementers have generally taken the sentence 'When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to.' as applying to `void` pointers.

Comment: @DanAllen I like your comment very much, especially "*it's fair to ask whether they can be (relationally) compared*".

Comment: @dlask However I don't think graphics_master is asking the question at the level formal compliance that you are. GM is asking 'how do I compare void*' to which the answer is 'easily'. We're discussing how that is formally defined by the language specification to which the answer is sort of and at best implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare directly .

```
int main(void)
{
  int a[]={10,20};
  void *p1=&a[0],*p2=&a[1];
  if(p1>p2)
   printf("Crazy\n");
  else
   printf("Correct\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Correct
```

Comment: I've modified this answer. It was undefined behavior. `a` and `b` don't point to the same object or two objects in the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other variable.

`if(a < b)`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdint.h>

if ( (uintptr_t)a < (uintptr_t)b ) ...
```

Please note that typecast to `int` could be insufficient on systems with 32bit integers but 64bit pointers.

Answer (score -3):

Every address is ultimately an number, a very long one but a number, so by doing a cast to an int(on a 64 bit system) or int64 you can compare the 2 values

```
if((int64)a < (int64)b)
{
.....
}
```

Comment: You don't need to convert them to integers. And if you for some reason need to do that, you should be using uintptr_t anyhow.

Comment: There is no need to perform this cast and it could confound the 'right' semantics because it will perform a signed comparison. You could (in principle) have an array in an unsigned address space (usual) where a precedes b in an array but a<b is false!